# Linking Parse Core to Apple Watch in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have incorporated Parse Core successfully into my Apple Watch application, however, I was initially having trouble getting my application to send data (using the initial TestObject tutorial).

I realized the problem was that the application has to be opened from the iPhone for it to trigger the send. When opening the application from the Apple Watch, no data is ever sent. After using the phone to trigger the application, the data was sent successfully.

All my code was incorporated into the AppDelegate.swift file as specified (as I said before it all works, compiles and no warnings). I assumed that changing the target membership would suffice, but this is not the case.

This is what my targets currently look like (the WatchKit App checkbox is grayed out too):

[image]

Setting the target to watchMenu WatchKit Extension triggers many (over 30) Mach-O Linker Errors. Here's an example of these errors:

```
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you update the membership of the components required by Parse as well

- AudioToolbox.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- Security.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libz.dylib
- libsqlite3.dylib